# jQuery Greyscale Plugin clashing with jQuery Cycle

Tags: jquery, cycle

Check out this lovely page - http://subzerostudio.com/Clients/montecarlo/gallery2.php -

I have used this plugin - http://www.pryde-design.co.uk/2011/08/greyscale-jquery-plugin/ - ( by Andrew Pryde ) to greyscale the images and then fade them into colour on hover.

This was actually very easy to integrate and is a very nice plugin to use, however when I attempt to duplicate the  containing the images, in order to activate the jquery cycle plugin in which they sit - the greyscale plugin effectively crashes. Demo with can be seen here.. **http://subzerostudio.com/Clients/montecarlo/gallery2.php**

I've looked through the relevant jquery files and cannot see anything to suggest why this might be happening, although I am sure it is a result of the cycle plugin.

Any ideas as to how to get this behaving properly ?

Comment: Problem comes in greyscale.js at line 
imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

Comment: Well spotted hardik, I have commented this line out but (unsurprisingly) it breaks the script... do you know what I would need to do to get around this ? Or do I need to find another cycle friendly greyscale plugin?